# Does $f_n(x,\cdot)\to f(x,\cdot)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$ for almost every $x?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f,f_n\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Is it true that for almost every $x$, $f_n(x,\cdot)$ converges to $f(x,\cdot)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. If it is true, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

No, consider the characteristic functions of

$$[0,1]\times [0,1]$$

$$[0,1/2]\times [0,1], [1/2,1]\times [0,1],$$

$$[0,1/3]\times [0,1],[1/3,2/3]\times [0,1], [2/3,1]\times [0,1],$$

$$ \dots$$

Comment: Any questions?$\,$